# Should I use Linq To SQL directly in code behind or use some other approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

We are developing a project in `ASP.NET/C#` which is a not a very large project but a sizeable one. Currently we have developed few pages. I am talking from point of view of a single page right now.The approach is followed for every pages that has been developed so far.

In the code behind of my page we use `Linq To SQL` queries directly. The `insert operation` is done , `queries` to fill `dropdownlists` and other `database` related operations are used in code behind itself.

We use functions though.The same goes for other pages as well.

My question is should I include them in `class` files and then create `objects` and call appropriate methods to do my stuff?

If yes, should we create a single `class` or create one class per page. Is this called creating `Data Access Layer`.

Can anyone help me suggest a proper way to do this?

Is this approach a good programming practice.

This is a simple function that we are using in our code behind

```
public void AccountTypeFill()
        {
            //Get the types of Account ie Entity and individual
            var acc = from type in dt.mem_types
                       select type.CustCategory;
            if (acc != null)
            {
                NewCustomerddlAccountType.DataSource = acc.Distinct().ToList();
                NewCustomerddlAccountType.DataBind();  
            }
        }
```

Can anyone point a simple example referring to this query?

I hope my question makes sense.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't hard-code in the code-behind. Use Classes and it is not a matter of one class for each page.

These links will help:

[Designing A Data Access Layer in LINQ to SQL](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/designing-a-data-access-layer-in-linq-to-sql/)

[Can LINQ to SQL generated objects be decoupled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222895/can-linq-to-sql-generated-objects-be-decoupled)

[Where to put method code which is called on click of a button?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1817339.aspx/1?Where%20to%20put%20method%20code%20which%20is%20called%20on%20click%20of%20a%20button%20)

[LINQ to SQL and the repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460882/linq-to-sql-and-the-repository-pattern)

[Decoupling Business Logic Layer from the User Interface Layer using C#](http://aspalliance.com/1360_Decoupling_Business_Logic_Layer_from_the_User_Interface_Layer_using_C.all)

Comment: Thanks ,I will go through the links and get back to you.