# Separating Linq To SQL Queries from code behind files

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use Linq To SQL directly in code behind or use some other approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271820/should-i-use-linq-to-sql-directly-in-code-behind-or-use-some-other-approach)

I already asked a question previously [**Separation Of Linq Queries from code behind.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271820/should-i-use-linq-to-sql-directly-in-code-behind-or-use-some-other-approach)

Maybe I could not get an answer I am looking for.So I am asking it once again.I use my `linq` to `Sql` queries in `code behind` directly.
I use functions though.

My question is how should I seperate them from `code behind`?

What is a better approach. Should I use simple `classes` and perform my `database` operations`(querying,insert,update,delete)` there and then just call those functions from code behind.

Is it the approach that I should follow. If yes then should I go for a single class or should I create one class per page.

Can anyone just guide me how should I organize this.What are the approaches that you guys follow?

I am using `ASP.NET Web Forms/C#`.

A simple example will be a huge help.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You may choose a N-Tier approach, where you will have a Data Access Layer, Business Layer and Presentation Layer. 
Your Data Access layer will have the LINQ to SQL stuff, your Business layer should work as a bridge between your data access layer and presentation (UI) layer.

Look at the following article: [Using LINQ to SQL in N-Tier Architectures](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33743/Using-LINQ-to-SQL-in-N-Tier-Architectures)

Comment: Thanks I will read the article and if any further help is required I will get back to you.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In some respects, LINQ queries shouldn't really be viewed as 'SQL' queries, even if they are then passed to a `LINQ2SQL` or an EF provider. LINQ expressions could arguably be viewed as flexible implementation of a query criteria pattern e.g. similar to [Evan's specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern), specifying 'what' you want returned, ideally keeping SQL Specifics on 'how' to do this at a minimum.

That said, it can make a system difficult to test if you expose your `DataContext` or an `IQueryable` directly to your presentation tiers. Typically, you may wish to consider constraining your LINQ expressions to a dedicated 'data tier'.

*Edit*

There is a similar discussion here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/linqtosql/thread/2df752fd-6a1d-441b-b7c4-ecf1a7a00161

and specifically, there is a generic repository pattern for Linq2SQL here
http://multitierlinqtosql.codeplex.com/

However, before implementing a heavily tiered architecture in Linq2SQL, you may reconsider replacing Linq2SQL with Entity Framework 4+. e.g. an issue with L2SQL is that the Entities are context-bound, meaning that you would need to map Simple data entities (POCOs) if you wanted to break the dependency on carrying your `DataContexts` around any layer which needs to use your entities. IMO Linq2SQL is best suited for small projects where you don't feel the need to abstract too much.

Comment: Can you point me to some examples of this solution.If possible.Thanks.